# Windows 8 XAML multi-column text

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, multiple-columns

Is there a way to make columns in a text?
I have one big string with the text i have to display, and i have a fixed height of the textblock, and have to make the text display in column.
like this image:[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked in the "common" folder of the default solution templates?  IIRC there is a control named something like ColumnTextBlock (or something similar) in there that does this for you.  If it isn't in the default template you use, try creating a new grid application and look in there - it gets used in the item detail XAML page.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The component is called `RichTextColumns` which should be in the `Common` folder of your default project directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

For a windows 8.1 Check out the samples from msdn:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-text-display-sample-2593ba0a/sourcecode?fileId=58034&pathId=615966648